# Publish multiple Gradle modules in one Maven artifact

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-publish

I have a library project that consists of two different APIs (`a` and `b`) which should operate on the same `core` and `base` code. `core` is hidden from the user of `a` or `b` so there is an `implementation` dependency to `core`. But `base` is exposed to the user of `a` or `b` so there is an `api` dependency to `base`.

[image: Module structure]

This is all fine as long as you stay in the Gradle world. But it becomes more complicated when you're publishing `a` and `b` with the `maven-publish` Gradle plugin. It creates an artifact of each of the modules separately and (correctly) outlines dependencies between them. But I don't want to expose `core` and `base` separately. Instead, I'd like to bundle them into one artifact for `a` and `b` each, where types in `core` stay internal and those in `base` are exposed.

Is there a way to do this with `maven-publish`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create a fat/uber JAR. There are plenty of tutorials out there, but a common approach is to use the Shadow plugin: https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/

You would configure the Shadow plugin to have `core` and `base` to be embedded/included in `a` and `b` without having to publish them.

Comment: thanks for the hint, definitely the right direction! i found no way to hide `core` from the library user, though. the only thing public to the user should be `api` and `common`. i tried around a long time now and found no way to achieve this with the shadow plugin. do you know of a way to do that? e.g. how could we set the visibility of all classes in `core` to `internal` during shadowing?

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 projects

`a    (api)` - depends on `base`, `core`
`b    (api)` - depends on `base`, `core`
`core (lib)` - depends on `base`
`base (api)` - none

assuming that all are building with `java-library` plugin.

If I got your question right - you want the end-users to see api's -`a, b, base` but not `core` - I am assuming this is applicable for DEV / Compile-time;

if above is correct - this is not with maven-publish; but rather dependency declaration

please see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation

in `a` and `b` build.gradle

```
api base
implementation core
```

in `core` build.gradle

```
api base
```